# Set data from an array of objects onto a card

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of objects with

1. image
2. title
3. price
4. vendor

I am trying to set each data on a card. I think I'm not accessing the array correctly.

I have an undefined error, how can I solve it? I appreciate your help

```js
const products = '[ { "user_id": "666", "products": [ { "id": "7109593301197", "name": "Product1", "img": "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/spunky-sam.png", "handle": "handle1", "price": "111.0", "vendor": "Vendor1" }, { "id": "7076369957069", "name": "Product2", "img": "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/purple-pi-pink.png", "handle": "handle2", "price": "85.0", "vendor": "Vendor2" }, { "id": "7182779154637", "name": "Product3", "img": "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/mr-pants.png", "handle": "handle3", "price": "435.0", "vendor": "Vendor3" }] } ]';
const data = JSON.parse(products);
const cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName("related-prod-wrapper");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const currentCardElement = cardElements.item(i);
  const cardImage = currentCardElement.getElementsByClassName("image").item(0);
  cardImage.setAttribute("src", data[i].img);
}

const cardElements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("related-prod-detail");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const currentCardElement2 = cardElements2.item(i);

  const cardVendor = currentCardElement2.getElementsByClassName("vendor").item(0);
  cardVendor.innerHTML = data[i].vendor;

  const cardTitle = currentCardElement2.getElementsByClassName("title").item(0);
  cardTitle.innerHTML = data[i].name;

  const cardPrice = currentCardElement2.getElementsByClassName("precio").item(0);
  cardPrice.innerHTML = data[i].price;

}
```

```html
<div class="med-product-card">
  <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="related-prod-detail">
    <h3 class="vendor">Vendor</h3>
    <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
    <h3 class="precio">Precio</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="med-product-card">
  <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="related-prod-detail">
    <h3 class="vendor">Vendor</h3>
    <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
    <h3 class="precio">Precio</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="med-product-card">
  <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="related-prod-detail">
    <h3 class="vendor">Vendor</h3>
    <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
    <h3 class="precio">Precio</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact (and complete) error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @GregFenton They're not getting an error message. It's showing `undefined` in the web page, as you can see if you click on `Run code snippet`.

Comment: There's no need for two separate loops over the same array.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're attempting to loop over the `data` array. The information you're looking for is actually in the `products` array in the 0th element of `data`. Therefore instead of `data[i]` you need to use `data[0].products[i]`, like this:

```js
const products = '[ { "user_id": "666", "products": [ { "id": "7109593301197", "name": "Product1", "img": "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/spunky-sam.png", "handle": "handle1", "price": "111.0", "vendor": "Vendor1" }, { "id": "7076369957069", "name": "Product2", "img": "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/purple-pi-pink.png", "handle": "handle2", "price": "85.0", "vendor": "Vendor2" }, { "id": "7182779154637", "name": "Product3", "img": "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/mr-pants.png", "handle": "handle3", "price": "435.0", "vendor": "Vendor3" }] } ]';
const data = JSON.parse(products);
const cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName("related-prod-wrapper");

for (var i = 0; i < data[0].products.length; i++) {
  const currentCardElement = cardElements.item(i);
  const cardImage = currentCardElement.getElementsByClassName("image").item(0);
  cardImage.setAttribute("src", data[0].products[i].img);
}

const cardElements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("related-prod-detail");

for (var i = 0; i < data[0].products.length; i++) {
  const currentCardElement2 = cardElements2.item(i);

  const cardVendor = currentCardElement2.getElementsByClassName("vendor").item(0);
  cardVendor.innerHTML = data[0].products[i].vendor;

  const cardTitle = currentCardElement2.getElementsByClassName("title").item(0);
  cardTitle.innerHTML = data[0].products[i].name;

  const cardPrice = currentCardElement2.getElementsByClassName("precio").item(0);
  cardPrice.innerHTML = data[0].products[i].price;

}
```

```html
<div class="med-product-card">
  <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="related-prod-detail">
    <h3 class="vendor">Vendor</h3>
    <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
    <h3 class="precio">Precio</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="med-product-card">
  <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="related-prod-detail">
    <h3 class="vendor">Vendor</h3>
    <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
    <h3 class="precio">Precio</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="med-product-card">
  <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="related-prod-detail">
    <h3 class="vendor">Vendor</h3>
    <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
    <h3 class="precio">Precio</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note however, that this could be further simplified in to a single loop and improved by using a `<template>` element to hold each 'Card' HTML structure which you create and update as part of the loop. This way the number of items contained within the JSON can be completely dynamic without you needing to change any of your HTML or JS logic:

```js
const json = '[{"user_id":"666","products":[{"id":"7109593301197","name":"Product1","img":"https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/spunky-sam.png","handle":"handle1","price":"111.0","vendor":"Vendor1"},{"id":"7076369957069","name":"Product2","img":"https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/purple-pi-pink.png","handle":"handle2","price":"85.0","vendor":"Vendor2"},{"id":"7182779154637","name":"Product3","img":"https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/mr-pants.png","handle":"handle3","price":"435.0","vendor":"Vendor3"}]}]';
const data = JSON.parse(json);
const cardContainer = document.querySelector('#card-container');
const cardTemplate = document.querySelector('#card-template');

data[0].products.forEach(product => {
  const card = cardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).firstElementChild;
  card.querySelector('.related-prod-wrapper img').src = product.img;
  card.querySelector('.vendor').textContent = product.vendor;
  card.querySelector('.title').textContent = product.name;
  card.querySelector('.precio').textContent = product.price;
  cardContainer.appendChild(card);
});
```

```html
<div id="card-container"></div>

<template id="card-template">
  <div class="med-product-card">
    <div class="related-prod-wrapper">
      <img class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="related-prod-detail">
      <h3 class="vendor"></h3>
      <h3 class="title"></h3>
      <h3 class="precio"></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You also need to fix the first loop for the images.

Comment: @Barmar indeed, missed that one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is parsing the JSON into `data` and then you are iterating over `data.length`.  But the JSON is an array with only 1 element in it...therefore `data.length` is always going to be `1`.

I suspect what you want to be iterating over is `data.products`.

You could resolve this a few ways. The least-invasive change could be:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(products).products;
```

(notice the `.products` at the end of the line)